# Buffer.BlockCopy does not work on double array?

Tags: .net

the following code

```
double[] src = new[] { 1d, 1d, 2d };
double[] dst = new[] { 0d, 0d, 0d };
Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, 3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.Write(src[i] + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.Write(dst[i] + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

outputs

```
1 1 2 
0 0 0
```

i expected the same value on both lines?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AH2ebt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling `BlockCopy` to copy 3 *bytes*. You want

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, 24);
```

or

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, 3 * sizeof(double));
```

... in order to copy all 24 bytes. The fifth parameter of [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy) is documented as:

> The number of bytes to copy.

*Not* the number of array elements to copy.

Comment: Oh thanks for the fast answer i guess i missed the "The number of bytes to copy." part of count!